# how to do this effect? when user scrolling browser then 50% scrolling in to and 50% scrolling at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to do this effect? when user scrolling browser then 50% scrolling in to and 50% scrolling at the bottom.

http://www.valentinagallo.us/site/#/collection/

Comment: how to do this effect? when user scrolling browser then 50% scrolling in top and 50% scrolling at the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just have two divs, each one has hidden overflow and static placement, then a large scrolling area behind it, an event listener that takes the amount scrolled on the page and uses a subtraction formula to get the inverse scroll amount from the bottom and then moves the nested div content accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to ask is: "How to make an element scroll in the opposite direction of the rest of the content."

The setup is roughly like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="leftContent">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="rightContent">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.leftContent {
  width: 50%;
}

.rightContent {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

JS:

```
const rightContent = document.querySelector('.rightContent');
document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, { passive: true });

function scrollHandler(event) {
  rightContent.style.bottom = (window.scrollY * -1) + 'px';
}

scrollHandler()
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/guidobouman/pen/BpyYxp